# convert .tif to png image android studio using https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory failed or?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, png

I'm here again. I was given a task to load an image in .tif file format in android studio.

My problem: The android studio phone first has to load the .tif image from the real phone and from .tif image convert .png.

what I used Image transformation libry: https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory.

```
Installation

Just add to your gradle dependencies :

1)implementation 'io.github.beyka:Android-TiffBitmapFactory:0.9.9.1'

And do not forget to add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to main project manifest
Build from sources

2)To build native part of library use Android-NDK-bundle.

3)To start build go to **tiffbitmapfactory folder** and run

4) ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=src/main
```

1. I have added gradle 2) I have downloaded ndk 3) and 4) I don't quite understand

I don't understand how to use this github project

**should I creat a JNI folder, and where and what should i install / put somthing in 3)tiffbitmapfactory folder**

Please can someone really help me ,please

Comment: What you have listed as 2, 3, and 4 are not needed, unless you are forking the library and building it from source ("Build from sources"). If you simply want to *use* the library, you only need step 1.

Comment: oh, so it makes sence ! thank for your comment!! This is very helpful for me !